# Orchard TinyMCE Configuration

Tags: tinymce, orchardcms-1.6

I am using the TinyMCE Deluxe module for Orchard to support additional editing options for a site. One of the things my client needs is the ability to do text alignment, identical to how Word works. I saw TinyMCE has a utility does support these options as part of the "Core" set of controls ([see here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Controls)), but when I try to edit orchard-tinymce.js to support core, I just start getting JS errors and the toolbar doesn't show up.

Any suggestions on how to add in the alignment options?

**EDIT**

Here is my orchard-tinymce.js file (located in /Modules/TinyMceDeluxe/Scripts):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
tinyMceDeluxe = new TinyMceDeluxe.Orchard();

// 1st arg is an array of plugin names. See plugin link above for full list of available plugins
// 2nd arg is an options object; also see TinyMce documentation for details on all available options. 
tinyMceDeluxe.init(['pagebreak', 'paste', 'table', 'template', 'syntaxhl'], {
    theme: "advanced",
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "tinymce",
    plugins: "fullscreen,autoresize,searchreplace,mediapicker,inlinepopups,-table,-pagebreak,-template,-paste,-syntaxhl",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: "true",
    //theme_advanced_buttons1: "search,replace,|,cut,copy,paste,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,charmap,emoticon,codeblock,|,bold,italic,|,numlist,bullist,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,styleselect,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'core',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "mediapicker,|,tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,visualchars,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify,|,syntaxhl,code,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    convert_urls: false,
    template_external_list_url: "/modules/tinymcedeluxe/scripts/samples/tinymce_template_list.js",
    // content_css sets the path to your site's main .css file. The styles from this file are imported into a droplist in the TinyMce editor. 
    // TinyMceDeluxe sets this path automatically to the /Styles/custom.css file in your site's theme, but you can override the path by declaring it here:
    //content_css: '/path/to/your/stylesheet.css',
    valid_elements: "*[*]",
    // shouldn't be needed due to the valid_elements setting, but TinyMCE would strip script.src without it.
    extended_valid_elements: "script[type|defer|src|language]"
});
```

});

I comment out theme_advanced_buttons1 which has a number of specific ones and changed it to just 'core' instead. When I do this, I get an error in tiny_mce.js on line one that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propery 'Button' of undefined."

Comment: show us some code of what you have set in the config and what errors you get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit to answer Thariama's question, I found [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x%3aButtons/controls) page on the TinyMCE website. I had been using buttons of "alignleft", "alignright" (and so on) for the alignment controls which I had seen elsewhere on their site, but it turns out the real names were "justifyleft", "justifyright", etc. Changing it to those gave me all the alignment options I needed.